# Error in dataparsing.nullpointer exception in custom listview

Tags: android, android-listview

i am creating custom listview. passing data to the edittext . at that time it shows an error

```
                i try this code
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     final ViewHolder holder;


        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editfoodmenulistview, null);
            holder.caption = (EditText) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.foodmenu);

            holder.caption1=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.foodimage);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //Fill EditText with the value you have in data source

        holder.caption.setText(itemnames[position]);
        holder.caption.setId(position);
        holder.caption.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        holder.caption1.setImageBitmap(bmps[position]);    

        //we need to update adapter once we finish with editing
        holder.caption.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus)
            {
                    final int position = v.getId();      
                    final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                    Caption.setFocusable(true);

                    holder.caption.setFocusable(true);
                    arr.remove(holder.caption.getId());
                    arr.add(holder.caption.getId(),holder.caption.getText().toString());


            }
                }

        });  



        return convertView;
    }
     }

      view holder(this is class)

 class ViewHolder {
 EditText caption;
ImageView caption1;
}

 class ListItem {
String caption;
}
```

the above viewholder class i used some other class get edittext. now i want reuse same edittext to another class.. it shows an error..please tell me how to solve the error

Comment: Hey can you add Logcat here ,so that may  help to solve problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editfoodmenulistview, null);
```

To this:

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editfoodmenulistview, parent, false);
```